# Create a dynamic excel sheet linked to a shapefile's attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, excel, dynamic

I am trying to create an excel sheet that is updated automatically when the features of a shapefile are updated.  I know the shapefile's .dbf file is updated but I need the excel sheet to be formatted for presentation purposes (borders, bold meaningful column headers, etc).  Right now I have created an excel sheet that links to the fields of the dbf but that isn't perfect...ie when a feature of the shapefile is deleted you now have excel fields linked to dbf fields that no longer exist.  Does anyone have any better ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a very old question but I wanted to share a rather roundabout way of loading shapefile dbfs in Excel using ODBC and Power Query.

The info below is very Excel-heavy and maybe not so suited to GIS.SE but I think there are still a lot of people who need to present linked shapefile data with Excel formatting and features. I find it powerful (albeit hacky) because you can do all your spatial based queries and data editing in a GIS program and immediately update the results in a nicely formatted spreadsheet with renamed columns ready for presentation or further analysis, without needing to worry whether you've got the latest values, etc.

In essence it's like loading an SQL VIEW into Excel.

---

## Pros

- Dynamic data from shapefile (press Alt-F5 to refresh)
- Lets you have shapefile simultaneously open/edited in another program
- Retain "friendly" aliases for 10-character shapefile column names without needing to rename each time
- Pre-filter data so you only load the relevant columns
- Keep Excel features even if data source or values change (e.g. pivot tables, conditional formatting, graphs)
- Use data with other Power Query or Excel functions
- Reusable in a template along with other Excel features
- No coding required for many implementations, familiar GUI

## Cons

- Can be quite slow (much faster to use sqlite)
- Shapefile must be on local/mounted drive
- Shapefile file name restrictions?
- Read-only (which is how it should be)
- Requires complicated workaround for file path if file is shared between different users on OneDrive
- No geometry data (not stored in dbf)

---

## Requirements

- Office 2016 onwards or Office 365 (which is what I've tested it in).
- Shapefile filename must not start with a numeric digit
- Shapefile must be on local or mounted drive, i.e. C:\, T:\ - no network paths or UNC syntax (\server-name...)
- In some instances, Shapefile filenames must be 8 characters or less (8.3 specification) ^

^ This has been the case for me in the 2 or so years I've been using this method, but testing it now, the ODBC driver in O365 version 2001 on W10 1909 seems to work with longer filenames.

---

## Method

1. Data tab > Get Data > From Other Sources > From ODBC
2. Select 'dBase Files' under Data source name (DSN)
3. Under Connection string, type dbq= followed by your file path (WITHOUT quotes), and **ensure there is a trailing backslash at the end**
   [image]
4. Select Default or Custom when the authentication window pops up, leave the credential connection string properties blank and click Connect
   [image]
5. Expand your folder in the Navigator window that pops up and select your relevant shapefile - if it loads in Preview click Load
   [image]
6. Your shapefile dbf data is now loaded as a Table from a Query in a new Excel Sheet. 
   [image]

---

## Refreshing data

- To get the latest data, click on the Table and hit alt-F5 to refresh the Query. (you will see any progress in the bottom toolbar of the main Excel window)
- If you have modified the cell contents or column names, order etc. in Excel and not Power Query, they will be overwritten with the shapefile data. You need to edit column names, column order in PQ so they stick (see Transforming Data below), much like defining a VIEW in SQL
- To disable auto adjustment of column widths on reload, click on the table, go to Table Design tab > Properties and uncheck Adjust column width

## Exporting static data

- If you delete the Sheet, the data is still in the Query as a connection, and you can re-load it (or combine it with other Queries)
- To permanently disable the data connection from the Sheet and make it a normal, editable Excel spreadsheet, click on the Table, go to the Table Design tab, and click Unlink. However the data connection is still in the background and may throw up error/warning messages if other people try to load the workbook
- To delete the data connection from the entire workbook go to Data tab > Queries & Connections and delete the query from the sidebar that pops up (right click > Delete)

## Transforming data

You can filter out, rename or transform columns in the Query persistently (so that the changes stick even after refresh) in the Power Query Editor.

1. Go to Data > Queries & Connections
2. Right click on your data table in the Queries & Connections sidebar that appears in the main window, and click Edit. This will open Power Query Editor.
3. You can now remove, rename, or rearrange columns using the GUI. You can also transform some values (e.g. find and replace, replace NULLs, concatenate or split columns). Each step is recorded in the Applied Steps list in the right hand side of the main window; you can undo steps by clicking on the X
4. You can also join or append multiple shapefiles by importing each shapefile as a separate query, then using the Power Query GUI (Home > Combine) to join/append those queries.

## Changing data sources

1. Open the query in Power Query Editor (see steps 1 and 2 above)
2. Click on the cog next to Source
3. Change the filepath after 'dbq='... remembering to leave a backslash at the end of the filepath
4. Go through the file navigation steps again, but the other steps in your query (renaming columns, etc.) will remain. If those columns no longer exist though you will get an error and you will need to modify your steps.

---

## Tips

- To change your query programmatically go to Advanced Editor in the Power Query Editor and modify accordingly (using the [Power Query M formula language](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/))
- Consider using Parameters in Power Query so it is easier for users to enter e.g. the filename or path without having to edit the query steps using the Settings cog
- If using shared folders on OneDrive where the file path references the Windows username you will have to manually edit the M Query (refer to examples [here](https://querypower.com/2017/04/03/4-ways-to-get-username-in-power-query/)) which will no longer let you edit file paths etc using the Settings cog
- If your query takes ages to refresh consider removing any filters in Excel, or, if the shapefile is being used by another program, disable edit mode (e.g. yellow pencil in QGIS)
- If you want to update the pivot tables to read from the latest loaded query data, refresh the query table first before refreshing the pivot tables.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a similar task for presenting housing density schedules, I pulled in all of fields and entries into excell then used another sheet in the same book with if statements to summarise the data this avoids references to specific cells.